# How to setup proxy configs for Emacs Wanderlust?

Tags: email, emacs, proxy

I am using Emacs Wanderlust as text-based email client. The problem is that it doesn't work in the company where the proxy server is installed. I can successfully setup ELPA package management (in Emacs) to pass the proxy server, but NOT Wanderlust.

It seems that mutt (another text-based email client) doesn't support proxy. I found no information about this issue in Wanderlust.

Any idea would be appreciated. Thank you very much!!!

Hajime Zhao